# Creating an object relational schema from a Class diagram

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, oop, schema

I'd like some help converting the following UML diagram:

[UML Diagram](http://img268.yfrog.com/img268/356/oracleexample.png)

The diagram shows 4 classes and is related to a Loyalty card scheme for an imaginary supermarket.

I'd like to create an object relational data base schema from it for use with Oracle 10g/11g. Not sure where to begin, if somebody could give me a head start that would be great.

Looking for actually starting the schema, show abstraction, constraints, types(subtypes, supertypes) methods and functions.

Note:
I'm not looking for anyone to make any comments regarding the actual classes and whether changes should be made to the Diagram, just the schema.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What language are you going to use?  This isn't "do my work for me.com".  What have you got besides the picture?

Comment: Not sure what is expected from a schema. Not looking for someone to do it all for me just to get me going. Language to implement it with will be SQL. Thanks for viewing.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about how to create the mapping between the database and your object oriented design. This is a big topic and you will encounter what is called the impedance mismatch. A google search on ["impedance mismatch"](http://www.google.com/search?q=database+mapping+impedance+mismatch&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) will give many pointers to documentation.

A nice starting place is this blog post [a-journey-with-domain-driven-design-and-nhibernate](http://flux88.com/blog/a-journey-with-domain-driven-design-and-nhibernate-part-5/) which discusses to create a table per class, a table per class hierarchy or create a table per subclass. Looking at your design you also have to make this design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) mapping tool such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) could save you this headache of organizing your DBRM?

Otherwise, I would ask for more details about what you're trying to achieve so that I may help you further, perhaps.